# Build a pipeline job if there's a new commit to the repository

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pre-commit-hook

I recently assigned new members to the project and since it is too huge there are multiple commits everyday. There are multiple jobs on the jenkins server that are built pulling from this particular repo and I need a way to make sure that for every new commit, a build is triggered in the jenkins jobs. I understand that this can be easily achieved in a free style job with hooks but, the problem is all my jobs are pipeline jobs and have Jenkinsfiles to build them.

So I need to figure out a way to achieve build (for every commit made to the repository) from within a Jenkinsfile for the Pipeline jobs. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first clearify, in git to have build for every commit , you first need to create a hook or something similar which will push the commit to branch, otherwise the commit is not accessible from jenkins server unless you do not run jenkins on every developer machine or have dockerized jenkinses.

next step, you can use following code:

```
stage('Checkout') {
            checkout([$class                           : 'GitSCM',
                      branches                         : [[name: '**']],
                      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                      extensions                       : [],
                      submoduleCfg                     : [],
                      userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS',
                                                           name         : 'origin',
                                                           refspec      : '+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*',
                                                           url          : 'REPO URL TO CHECK OUT']]])

        }
```

and in Jenkins job config page put this config - http://prntscr.com/j0m6aq

So, this will means, checking will try to poll scm every minute, the code below will assure that the scm is polled for all active branches and pull requests that have new change. For the first run it will check all the branchec obviously and afterwards it will do execute your jenkinsfile only for branch(es) that have new changes.